# Google Pay Integration Issue in .NET MAUI Blazor Project

Tags: blazor, maui, .net-8.0, google-pay, maui-blazor

I am integrating Google Pay with my .NET 8 MAUI Blazor project, but I'm encountering issues. The JavaScript code works fine in a regular website project, allowing me to pay and debug using a "TEST" environment.

On **Android**, the app crashes, and I receive the following error:

> Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Message=uriString

using **Windows Machine**, the app opens the GooglePay website in the browser, but I encounter the following error:

> Something went wrong
> To make this purchase using Google Pay, open this website in a browser app, such as Chrome or Safari. [OR_BIBED_15]

[This is the JavaScript code](https://gist.github.com/gergesrami/20430b8adf3878228913d28a9f09675a)

I followed Google's tutorial and integrated the necessary JS code, and the script works as expected in a regular website project.

I expect the Google Pay integration to work within my .NET MAUI Blazor app, similar to how it functions in a regular website project.